# Select the value of dropdown when dynamically data loaded

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

- I am using select2 for dropdown
- When user enter the code in input field. If code exist than fetch the data against the code and fill the input fields using ajax.
- Problem is countries shown in dropdown. If value match than select the country and show the cities in next dropdown which is first empty.Because no country selected

I want to select the city if it is loaded in dropdown

```
//country selected against the value return from ajax request

$("#country").val(data[0]['PA_COUNTRY']).trigger('change');
<select id="country" name="country">
  <option value="1" selected>UK</option>
</select>

//Problem is city show late against country value
// Thats why below line not select any city

$("#city").val(data[0]['CITY']).trigger('change');  
var state = data[0]['city'];

//When city will be show selected if i set 1 second delay to show city in dropdown

setTimeout(function(){

//this will work but this is not proper solution
$("#inst_cmb_province").val(state).trigger('change');
}, 2000);
```

I also use to this to select the dropdown but this could not work

```
   $("#city").select2();
   $('#city').trigger("liszt:updated");
   $("#city").val(data[0]['CITY']).prop("selected", true);
   $("#city").select2();
  $('#city').trigger("liszt:updated");
```

Comment: why you are declaring select2  for city 2 times?

Comment: you should have the ajax for city select2, so when you slect a country, make a function for country change, and trigger city change , and in ajax, pass country as data, and it will load cities

Comment: initialize the select2();